# Previous data should be update in new field if it changes

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a field on a Sharepoint list called 'Current client'. When the name in this field changes I want to store this into a field called 'Previous client'

[image]

Comment: Is it a person or group field or single line of text?

Comment: it is drop down field.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SharePoint Designer workflow or Microsoft flow/Power Automate for such kind of requirements.

Here are the steps for this:

1. Create two new columns in SharePoint list and name it "Temporary Client" as "Previous client".
2. Make these fields hidden from list forms (content type).
3. Run the workflow/microsoft flow on item creation and item change event trigger.
4. Check the condition if `Current client is equal to Temporary Client`.
5. If the Current client is **not equal** to Temporary Client then update the Previous client field with Temporary client value. And update Temporary Client with Current client value.

Comment: Can you please help me configure the work here..

Comment: Or you can enable [Version history](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-list-or-library-1555d642-23ee-446a-990a-bcab618c7a37) on your list. That way you can track the changes in your column.

Comment: i think version history will not work for my senario.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, workflow is not working.

Comment: Will be both column in dropdown or test field ?

Comment: You can create "Temporary Client" as "Previous client" as single line of text columns as users are not going to enter/select value for this columns. we are updating this fields from workflow only.

Comment: Then, How will get user will get to know , which is the current client and which was the previous client.

Comment: You will add previous client field in your list view. So user can see the previous client as well as current client. and will able to change only current client on list form.

Comment: I have done the setup, How can i share the screenshot to you.

Comment: Some time it is working and sometime it is not working ,,Ganesh

Comment: You can add screenshot to your original question by editing it.

Comment: I have added the screenshot ganesh, Please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103765/discussion-between-ashanta-palei-and-ganesh-sanap).

Comment: Hi Ganesh, Can you please help me on this.

Comment: I have replied you in the chat. check above "continue this discussion in chat" link.